# Extract path from source(src) attribute in an HTML image tag(img)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to extract image paths from a database field that contains HTML.  The data in the database looks like this:

```
<p><strong><strong>DISCUSSION POINT</strong>: Nearly how many years did it take Sir Francis Drake to complete the first circumnavigation of the globe in 1580?&nbsp;<br /><p><img id="lk45459gjh4" src="../mediaForExam/dlfkeiut8484034djjd222.png" alt="dlfkeiut8484034djjd222.png" width="697" height="352" /></p>
```

From this string, I only need this part:

> /mediaForExam/dlfkeiut8484034djjd222.png

I tried this query:

```
SELECT RIGHT(questionText, (LEN(questionText)-PATINDEX ( '%SRC="%' , questionText )-5)) AS MediaPath FROM exams.history
```

but it's returning a string like this:

> ./mediaForExam/dlfkeiut8484034djjd222.png"
>   alt="dlfkeiut8484034djjd222.png" width="697" height="352" />

Is there a way to only return the first slash, folder name, then file name( ie: /folderName/fileName.ext)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do :

```
select substring(hh.questionText, 1, charindex('"', hh.questionText) - 1)  as MediaPath 
from exams.history h cross apply
     ( values (stuff(questionText, 1, charindex('src=', questionText)+6, '')) 
     ) hh (questionText);
```

Comment: almost perfect! However there's a trailing quotation mark at the end of the result (ie /path/image.png").   Would there be a way to remove that?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell. . . That is what the query does. Re-copy the query & try.

Comment: I changed the the 1 to a 0 in the first substring call (substring(hh.questionText, 0, ...) and it got rid of the trailing quotation mark.  Thanks!